# Determinar que estamos utilizando el mecanismo del AMM (Automatic Memory Management) de Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Podrían ayudarme en como determinar que estoy utilizando el mecanismo del AMM (Automatic Memory Management) de Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AMM** esta destinado solo para bases de datos pequeñas, nunca debe habilitarse en bases de datos de produccion o mision critica, para eso un DBA debe configurar los parametros de una manera eficiente.

Ahora bien, dicho esto muy importante vamos a lo que necesitas.

Si el parametro `memory_target` esta configurado, es decir, tiene un valor diferente a cero entonces tienes habilitado **AMM**.

Ejecuta la siguiente instruccion para identificar el valor del parametro `memory_target`

```
SHOW PARAMETER TARGET
```

Esta seria la salida, y puedes notar que para este caso no esta habilitado **AMM**

```
NAME                          TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------ ----------- ----------------
archive_lag_target             integer     0
db_flashback_retention_target  integer     1440
fast_start_io_target           integer     0
fast_start_mttr_target         integer     0
memory_max_target              big integer 0
memory_target                  big integer 0
pga_aggregate_target           big integer 90M
sga_target                     big integer 272M
```

En este [ENLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory003.htm#ADMIN11200) pueden conseguir mayor informacion.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jbeltran